# Problems mainly based on a composite function $f(f(x))={f(x)}^3$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functional-equations

> For $f(x)$ which is differentiable over all $\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)$ meets four conditions
>
> (a) $f(4) < 1 $
>
> (b) For all $\mathbb{R}$, $f(f(x))={f(x)}^3$
>
> (c) if $p < q$, $0\le f(p) \le f(q)$
>
> (d).  if $p < q$, $f'(p) + \cfrac{3}{4}p \le f'(q) + \cfrac{3}{4}q$
>
> for all $f(x)$ that meets above conditions, $M(x)$ is the function where $f(4)$ become largest number. (maximum)
>
> Find the value of $$\int_{-2}^{2} M(x) dx$$
> Source: A Korean hs problem

I was struggling to understand what (b) means, and I couldn't figure it out from the start.

(detailed questions after some comments)

I was mainly curious about the condition (b).

Simply thought, $f(x)$ is $0$, $1$ or $x^3$

But it is not likely, because of the condition (a)

I think the problem wanted me to think about the domain and range of $f(x)$

But at that point, I wasn't able to move forward.

I don't know how to connect that thought with other conditions.

Comment: You gotta show your attempt, is M the function which satisfies this and maximizes f?

Comment: (b) means "For any $x$, if you work out $f(x)$, then sub *that* into $f$, you get the same as if you work out $f(x)$ and cube it."

Eg, if $f(x) = x^5$, then $f(f(x))=f(x^5)=(x^5)^5$, which is $x^{25}$. But $f(x)^3=(x^5)^3=x^{15}$. So $f(x)=x^5$ is not an example. However, if $f(x)=x^3$, then sure enough, $f(f(x))=x^9$, and also $f(x)^3=x^9$, so this function satisfies condition (b) [but not condition (a)]

Comment: Hint : Rearranging condition 'c' , we find: $ \frac{f'(p) - f'(q)}{p-q} \leq \frac{3}{4}$, take the limit as $ p \to q$ on LHS.

Comment: @Buraian Yes. M is the function that satisfies this and maximizes f, and thank you for the hint. I would try

Comment: (d) doesn't make any sense. Does $p>q$ for it? There should be some other constraint.

Comment: I'm confused at 3 + votes on a PSQ question.

Comment: I think it is mainly because it's difficulty is appealing to those in undergraduate/ highschool @Alan

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta (c) and (d) was originally in one sentence but it was edited. so the condition is same as (d)

Comment: My mistake, I have edited the question again. You may want to edit the question with an attempt to prevent it from being closed @SGKwon

Comment: I've added to my answer @SGKwon

Comment: Did you solve this? :-)

Comment: @Buraian I couldn't... Techniques for solving this kind of problem is way beyond my skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some observations:

1. Rearranging condition 'd' , we find: $ \frac{f'(p) - f'(q)}{p-q} \leq \frac{3}{4}$, take the limit as $ p \to q$ with $p>q$ on LHS. Take the upper side limit to avoid problems:
   $$ \lim_{ p \to q^+} \frac{ f'(p) - f'(q)}{q-p} \leq \frac34$$

We find that: $ -f''(x) \leq \frac34$(*)

3. Equation b, we find that if $f(x)=0$ at any $ x \in \mathbb{R}$ , then it must be that $x=0$ is a zero for the function as well.
4. The c. condition can be written as: $f'(x) \geq 0$
5. If $f(4)<1$, then it must be that $f(f(4))<f(4)$, by the facts that $f(4)<4$ and $f(x)$ is an increasing function.

We can also prove by induction on the above fact that upon setting the number of compositions to infinity, the function goes to zero. Since $0 \leq f(x)$, we find the lower bound is zero.

6. (From Lutz Lehman) , if a function is continuous for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then it must be that the range can be written as an open interval $(0,b)$. Further, we can identify a polynomial equation which the upper bound must satisfy.

Let $b$ be the upper bound, if $b>1$ then $f(b) \geq b$, then $b^3 \geq b$, this is only without contradiction if $b^3 = b$.

If $b<1$, then we find that $1 \leq b$

Hence, we arrive at the conclusion of Lutz Lehman on the bounds:

$$0 \leq b <1$$

---

**Example function:**

As noted by Lutz Lehman, $f(x)=0$ seems to be a function satisfying the criteria in the question + the ones derived above.

---

*: I assumed existence of second derivative to make this work, otherwise there is no reason for upper limit and lower limit to agree.

**: I assumed $f'(x) \neq 0$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128132/discussion-on-answer-by-buraian-problems-mainly-based-on-a-composite-function-f).